# woocommerce - undelete posts

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I manage a store that deleted several products recently, I am trying to re-instate them.

We use sage for our stock and ordering, it's linked in with eureka / patchworks.

We deleted some products from stock, so we deleted them from woo, and emptied the trash. Now we have these items back in stock.

I am not able to list these products again.

I think I need to do something in the database, but I don't know what, exactly. I am using cloudways and their database manager.

Any help appreciated, I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: When you empty the trash, WooCommerce posts are deleted from the database forever. If you don't have backups - no way.

Comment: I'm trying to re-add the products, but it will not let me. I'm trying to use the same SKU - so there might be a trace of it in the database.

If it's been marked as deleted, and I'm trying to add it as a new product, why will it not let me?

Comment: No trace in database after deleting the product. Error is somewhere else. You have to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve